# What is the best cross-platform GPL personal finance tool available?

Tags: online-tools, websites, gnucash

If I want desktop, web and mobile (preferably Android) access to all my accounts and assets, in a personal finance tool, what would you recommend I look at?

Until Wesabe cancelled their web dashboard it was a pretty good online tool. I use GNUCash on my desktop.

Is there a cross-platform tool that provides a fairly consistent user experience and doesn't require a too strong focus on double entry?

Comment: `best` is rather subjective.  The text of the question itself though, is not.  I suggest that you edit the title of the question to remove `best` from it.

Comment: Do you want GPL? or just open source?

Comment: Alex B: Anything that runs on any one of these licenses :http://opensource.org/ or are run are run as an always free service.

Comment: George: true best is subjective. How do I go about editing titles?

Comment: Near the bottom of the question (above these comments) there is an "Edit" link.  That will allow you to edit the question title, the text of the question itself and the tags.  You can even provide a summary of the changes, which shows up in the revision history as guide to the revision.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't one. I haven't been very happy with anything I've tried, commercial or open source. I've used Quicken for a while and been fairly happy with the user experience, but I hate the idea of their sunset policy (forced upgrades) and using proprietary format for the data files. Note that I wouldn't mind using proprietary and/or commercial software if it used a format that allowed me to easily migrate to another application. And no, QIF/OFX/CSV doesn't count.

What I've found works well for me is to use **[Mint.com](http://www.mint.com)** for pulling transactions from my accounts and categorizing them. I then export the transaction history as a CSV file and convert it to QIF/OFX using **[csv2ofx](http://github.com/mulicheng/csv2ofx)**, and then import the resulting file into **[GNUCash](http://www.gnucash.org/)**. The hardest part is using categories (Mint.com) and accounts (GnuCash) properly. Not perfect by any means, but certainly better than manually exporting transactions from each account.

Comment: I also use gnuCash on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I use "[Money Manager Ex](http://www.codelathe.com/mmex)" which is a Windows application I use on PC to log my transactions and for simple statistic.

They have two versions, simple standlone application and self-hosted web app.

Comment: Interesting.  A self-hosted web app?  I can't seem to find a reference to that on their website.

Comment: I also wanted to point out that the desktop application is available for Linux and Mac OSX.

Comment: @George Marian, it is the Tonido's edition. http://www.tonido.com/app_money_home.html