# Website for managing personal cash inflow and outflow, applicable to India?

Tags: india, online-tools, websites, cash-flow

Is there any website that helps me to manage my Daily Cash Inflow and Cash Outflow. 
 I would like to have the following feature.

1. Periodically I should be able to enter my Cash Inflow (salary, gift, borrowed money,etc.,) and Cash Outflow (electricity bill, house rent, gas,etc.,)
2. Classify my spending as "Mandatory","CanBeReduced" and "NotRequired".  For eg., I will classify my house rent, education fees,etc,. as "Mandatory",  "Party","Travel",etc., can be classified as "CanBeReduced", "Movies","Smokes",etc., can be classified as "NotRequired".
3. Set a Target saving by a particular Day (for eg., I want to save 1000$ by June 2013).  Based on target it should suggest me which spending I can reduce,etc.,
4. Generate month wise / Year wise report on Income and Expense.

I referred the following Questions before posting.

1. [Personal budget forecast/tracking solution](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7769/personal-budget-forecast-tracking-solution?rq=1)
2. [best free web app or tools to track one's cash flow](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15725/best-free-web-app-or-tools-to-track-ones-cash-flow?rq=1)
3. [What is the best cross-platform GPL personal finance tool available?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2930/what-is-the-best-cross-platform-gpl-personal-finance-tool-available?rq=1)
4. [Is there any online personal finance software without online banking?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/8587/is-there-any-online-personal-finance-software-without-online-banking)

Note : I am from India.

Comment: I checked on mint.com but it is not available for India :-(

Comment: I can't find proof, but yodlee.com?  They have offices in India and some articles seem to indicate they are working with Indian banks.

Answer (score 1):

There are sites in India that offer this, http://www.intuit.in/ is one such site. Apart from this some banks like ICICI offer this to limited extent.

Answer (score 0):

You might like https://planwise.com/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

https://moneycenter.yodlee.com/

You can link your bank accounts, credit cards, trading accounts etc at Yodlee. These will be updated automatically if you share your username and password from your existing financial institutions.

You also have the option of creating manual accounts. You will have to manually add/update transactions.

Comment: Saw this there: *"In order to register or use Yodlee MoneyCenter, you must be at least 18 years old, **a United States resident** and legally capable to enter into contracts."*  The OP is in India.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Pocketsmith](http://www.pocketsmith.com) for simple cashflow forecasting. I use [Moneycenter](http://moneycenter.yodlee.com) for more complex tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Use buxfer.com. It's available in India and most of the features are free.

Comment: Welcome Ash.  Could you please explain how you came to this choice so that we can vote on not only your answer, but also the process you used to find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mint.com attaches to all your accounts and lists all your transactions.  I love it.

Comment: In India?  I thought mint.com was limited to the United States and Canada?